# How to know if a RadToolBarButton is checked or not with JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I'd like to know if there is a way to tell if the RadToolBarButton "Filter" is checked or not using JS.

```
    <telerik:RadToolBar ID="SelectionToolBar" runat="server" OnButtonClick="SelectionToolBar_Click" OnClientButtonClicking="clientButtonClicking">
            <Items> 
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton Value="Flagged" Text="Flagged Reports" Group="ViewMode" CheckOnClick="true"/>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton Value="Separator" IsSeparator="true"/>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton IsSeparator="true"/>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton ImageUrl="~/images/refresh.png" Value="Refresh" ToolTip="Refresh"/>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton IsSeparator="true"/>
                <telerik:RadToolBarButton Value="Filter" ImageUrl="~/images/funnel.png" CheckOnClick="true" Checked="false" AllowSelfUnCheck="true" ToolTip="Toggle Filters"/>
            </Items>     
        </telerik:RadToolBar>
```

Since RadToolBarButton is a subset of RadGridSelectionToolBar I wasn't sure how to get the property of one specific button.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [get_checked](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tool_clientsidetoolbaritem.html) client property of RadToolBarButton inside the OnClientButtonClicking handler you wired? That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a really old question, but here the exact answer for your question for future references:

```
function clientButtonClicking(sender, args) {
        var val = button.get_value();
        if(val !== "Filter"){
            return false;
        }
        var checkState = args.get_item().get_checked();
    }
```